# Grails and 3rd party tool use same database: how to update grails after 3rd party deletes?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm writing a Service method (Grails 2.5.5) which deletes entities using a 3rd party rest API. Partway through my method, I call `.refresh()` on one of the entities, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException: No row with the given identifier exists: [MyEntity#7103]; nested exception is org.hibernate.UnresolvableObjectException: No row with the given identifier exists: [MyEntity#7103]
```

which is true since I just deleted it using the REST API. If it matters, the deleted MyEntity is in a `hasMany` on the entity I'm trying to refresh. I don't (think I) want to mark this as `ignoreNotFound`.

How do I tell Grails/Hibernate that it's ok that this record no longer exists?

Comment: ha, I just ran into this problem again and for a moment was very excited that Google had found such a useful SO question for me!

Answer (score 1):

I faced with same issue and found next solution.

So you have entity E that has list of entities A.
In case you need to delete entity A you need to do following:

```
 public void deleteA(List<Integer> ids) {
    if (!ids) {
        return
    }
    List<A> aToDelete = A.findAllByIdInList(ids)
    aToDelete.each { A a ->
        if(a.e) {
            E e = a.e
            e.a.remove(a)
        } else {
            a.delete()
        }
    }
}
```

So the idea is to check if A has any relation to E in case yes delete it via E otherwise delete it directly. For me works fine.

Comment: Both the 3rd party tool and my grails webapp look at the same database. If I delete an entity using the 3rd party tool's REST API (usually involves deleting rows in multiple tables) then how can grails be informed of what was deleted?